# decreasing sequence for sin

Tags: analysis

I want to show that a sequence $\sin(n\pi x)$ where $x$ is in $[0,1]$ is decreasing? 
is there any test I can apply and if there is no test can somebody please tell me how to show it?

since I think that i am doing wrong. what I did:

$\sin((n+1)\pi x)=\sin(n\pi x+\pi x)=\sin(n\pi x)\cos(n\pi)+\sin(n\pi)\cos(n\pi x)<\sin(n\pi x)$ but why???

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. Let $x = \frac{1}{2}$. Then your sequence is $0, 1, 0, -1, \dots$.

Comment: actually i was trying to show that a sequence of series uniform convergence by using Abel's Test and function in the sum includes term of sin(nπx) and i have to show that this is decreasing but how?any comment.

Comment: Well, if you want an answer to that question, then I think it would be good for you to ask it.

Comment: ok. the series is Un(x)=A(x+ (sum sign ((-1)^n/n) e^(-n^2 π^2 t) sin(nπx)) i need to use Abel test I checked everything except for monotonic decreasing.

Comment: I meant ask it as a new question. And when you do, take the time to format the math symbols properly.

Answer (score 0):

As wckronholm says, you can see that the statement is wrong because $x=\frac12$ produces an oscillating sequence. In fact, any nonzero rational number will produce an oscillating sequence. Irrational numbers will exhibit similar up-down-up behavior but they will not actually repeat numerically.

As for the argument, it has a typographical error which turns out to be fatal: it states that $\sin(n\pi x + \pi x) = \sin(n\pi x)\cos (n\pi) + \sin(n\pi)\cos(n\pi x)$ but what is actually true is that
$$\sin(n\pi x + \pi x) = \sin(n\pi x)\cos (\pi x) + \sin(\pi x)\cos(n\pi x)$$
from which the final inequality no longer follows.